# Gradle error casusing the vs code to not to debug properly

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

When I tried to debug my flutter code in my computer vscode debug console just show the error

```
aunching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1474)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1482)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1320)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:186)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

as an error and exit it from their. Either the emulator works or not the error is still keep coming
whatever I tried.

I hoping to get a good answer to this error as I can't go any further without resolving this problem.

Comment: Looks like one of your zip files is corrupt, but it isn't immediately obvious which one.  If you haven't included any directly, you could start with your grade distributions (`~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`), and also caches (~/.gradle/caches).